# How to render 3D models as SVG vector graphics? (planar projection)

Tags: software-recommendation, 3d, svg

[image]

This image ([original SVG from Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Rhomboederstumpf_SketchUp_massiv.svg), public domain) was created using the following procedure:

1. Create a 3D model in Google sketchup
2. Export as PDF
3. Import in Inkscape
4. Save as SVG

Is there a straightforward way to produce such a SVG with software that runs (natively) on Ubuntu? ([Pantograph](https://severnclaystudio.wordpress.com/bluebeard/pantograph-download/), a Blender plugin, has only broken download links; [VRM](http://vrm.ao2.it/section/en/about.html), another Blender plugin works with Belnder 2.4x, but not with Blender 2.6x.)

Comment: Well It's all a matter of Shadows and lights.. not difficutl to do, and Inkscape has a 3D tool only it's a rectangle.

Comment: It's a matter of light, shadows ann perspective. This is quite difficult to do in Inkscape unless all your objects are rectangular and aligned with the axes of Inkscape's isometric ("3D") grid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two options:

**Option 1**

The first requires a recent builds of Blender (available from [Graphicall](http://www.graphicall.org/)), which can now use the [Freestyle](http://freestyle.sourceforge.net/) rendering engine

> Freestyle is a software for Non-Photorealistic Line Drawing rendering
>   from 3D scenes.

Within Freestyle there exists a plugin, [SVGWriter](http://www.geocities.jp/blenderyard/freestyle/svgwriter_b26/README.html), that can write Blender scenes to SVGs. Instructions for usage are available on that page. Below is an example of its output:

Original Blender render:
[image]

Freestyle SVG output:
[image]

Freestyle is still in development and you can follow its progress on [their blog](http://freestyleintegration.wordpress.com/).

The still image SVG writer in SVGWriter currently only renders one image i.e. you can't render each frame to an SVG. I've rewritten the script to do this, and the author has informed me that my modification will be integrated into the main download in a future update. [Here is the modification](http://pastebin.com/qMus9VzU)

**Option 2**

The second option only allows you to render bezier curves. First, you must install [svgwrite](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/svgwrite) for Python 3. You can do this by going into the folder and running

```
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

You may need to copy the svgwrite folder into .blender/version_number/python/lib/python3.2/

You then need to download [SVGwriter](https://gitorious.org/blender-2-6-svg-export) for Blender. Install Git and then run

```
git clone git://gitorious.org/blender-2-6-svg-export/blender-2-6-svg-export.git
```

Inside the downloaded folder you will need to copy the Python scripts (those ending in .py) and overwrite the ones located either in ./blender/[version_number]/scripts/addons/io_curve_svg/ or in /usr/lib/blender/scripts/addons/io_curve_svg/ .

Finally, in Blender, draw your bezier curve and then go to File > Export > SVG. Here's an example of the output

Original Blender curve
[image]

SVG output. The line thickness was increased for clarity
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are many  free plugins for Sketchup and one of those does just what you require,and you dont need to buy Sketchup pro. By the way it is able to export many types of 3D formats via free plugins also.
Check your info before giving poor advice C.S Cameron

[Here is the plugin page for reference](http://code.google.com/p/sketchup-svg-outline-plugin/)

Comment: Good to know. What a pitty Google doesn't make a Linux version. Will try with VirtualBox.